# Url.RouteUrl returning empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I´m trying to get full URL but the `RouteUrl` is returning empty.

In the View, I´m calling like that:

```
alert('@Url.RouteUrl("Api", new { controller = "Parametros", id = "" })');
```

Here is my routes configurations:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Api",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Usuario",
            action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and my controller:

```
public class ParametrosController : ApiController
{
    ISistemaService _sistemaService;
    public ParametrosController(Empresa empresa, ISistemaService sistemaService)
    {
        _sistemaService = sistemaService;
    }


    public PagedDataModel<ParametroDTO> Get(
        [FromUri]ParametroFiltro filter, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        int total = 0;
        var list = _sistemaService.Paging(filter, page, pageSize, out total);
        return new PagedDataModel<ParametroDTO>(page, pageSize, total, list);
    }

    public ParametroDTO Get(string codigo)
    {
        return _sistemaService.GetParametroPorCodigo(codigo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `httproute = ""` to the `routeValues`:

```
alert('@Url.RouteUrl("Api",
     new { httproute = "", controller = "Parametros", id = "" })');
```

Comment: Ok it worked. tks a lot, but I didn´t understand why I need this parameter?

Comment: You need this parameter in order to indicate to the routing engine that you need to generate an API route and not a standard MVC route.